# Heap's algorithm handling duplicates

Tags: python

I have a simple Heap's algorithm, with an input of a = [0, 1, 2, 2], i don't have any idea on how to modify
the code, co that it wont print out duplicates. I alredy now how many there will be permutations if there's a repeated number (in this example [0, 1, 2, 2], 2s are repeated 2 times, so 2! = 2, so 24/2 = 12). I don't want to use another list to see the "seen" permutations (too long, it must be time efficent). Thanks for the help.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
length = len(a)

def heapPermutation(a, size):
    
if size == 1:
    print(a)
    return

for i in range(size):
    heapPermutation(a, size-1)
    
    if size % 2 == 1:
        a[0], a[size-1] = a[size-1], a[0]
    else:
        a[i], a[size-1] = a[size-1], a[i]

heapPermutation(a, length)
```

/\ thats the code

Comment: use `set` to avoid printing duplicate

Comment: I need all of those numbers in the input, even the duplicates

Comment: you can still use a set to keep track of the unique permutations without excluding any numbers

Comment: so add a list with the permutations, and then use the set? doesnt the set only work for ints?

Comment: Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: yes! it works, i forgot that u can setup a set first, and then add elements to it (needed tuples, lists are unhashable). thanks guys for help and have a great day :)

Comment: still have a question tho, if i have a 12-digit number (around 480m permutations), but with all of the duplicates the number of unique permutations is around 455k (the number is 2 0 2 3 2 0 2 3 2 0 2 3), is it possible to modify the heaps algorithm, so that it will only print out the unique permutation (while do algorithm is active, not after its done)? if it isnt possible ill look for another algorithm